# Stop retry when throw exception inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have controller action:

```
    // Client
    public static async Task<ActionResult> DownloadAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var fileContents = await client.Get();
            return File(fileContents, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        }
    }

    // Controller
    public byte[] Get()
    {
        var data = GetByteAsync(...);
        if (data != null)
            return data;
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
```

When my controller throw exception, seem like it auto-retry calls API again few times before return to the client, so is any way to prevents that?

Comment: I don't think `HttpClient` has any built-in retry logic? Are you sure you're not calling `DownloadAsync` again if it fails once?

Comment: I don't see how any of this code is joined together. Is this code in one codebase, or does it represent client-server applications?